# BigQuery how to group by after flattening a collection of tables over timerange

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to do the following:

1. combine tables over a timerange using `FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE`
2. `FLATTEN` that set of data
3. `GROUP BY` ColumnX
4. SELECT ColumnX, SUM(ColumnY), SUM(ColumnZ) over only unique ColumnX values.

here's the gist of my query:

```
SELECT
  r.ColumnX
  ,SUM(r.ColumnY)
  ,SUM(r.ColumnZ)
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM FLATTEN(
    (
        SELECT
          ColumnX
          ,ColumnY
          ,ColumnZ

        FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(projectx.events_,
          TIMESTAMP('2015-09-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-09-08'))), my_funky_object
    )
    WHERE ColumnY > 10
) r
GROUP BY
  r.ColumnX
```

The problem is, I get a number of rows WAY GREATER than the count of unique values of ColumnX should. So I took a step back and simply outputted the GROUP BY - COUNT of ColumnX in order to debug, and I get the following output!

and I get what looks like an intermediate result.

[image]

What is happening and how do I ensure that my outer select only aggregates over unique values of ColumnX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the count of each distinct value of ColumnX, but you're only showing the count, not the value.

If your goal is to get an accurate count for the number of distinct values, try something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) ct
FROM (
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    ... rest of your query ...
  GROUP BY r.ColumnX
)
```

That inner query will give you exactly one row (each with the value 1) for each distinct value of ColumnX. The outer select statement will count the number of such rows.

Another alternative is to use EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT to get the exact count of rows. That's simpler but less scalable than using GROUP BY.